# Scala Programming: Canonical way to convert a sequence of if else into a flow of map

Tags: scala, functional-programming

What is the preferred canonical method in Scala (or FP) of adapting complex chained `if...then...` statements?  For example (metacode):

```
def fetchLastOrderFor(CustomerId:UUID)= {
    fetch Customer data from an Id
    if Customer exists 
       fetch extra information for that customer (address?)
       fetch latest order of that customer
       if Order exists
          fetch OrderDetails
          ....
}
```

So far I'm modeling this as a sequence of nested `match...case Some...case None` returning something like `Either[MotivationOfMissingOrderReturned,OrderWithAllDetails]`

But I'm unsure if this is the best approach (it looks to me a bit ugly and difficult to read) or maybe I can model it with some kind of chained monad flow like `Try` or `map / filter`, `Future`s, maybe using elegant `for` comprehensions.

I'm new in FP and trying to grasp how to methodically convert my non-functional instinct into FP jargon.

I know that FP tends to avoid using `if... then ... else` in favour of collective actions made on containers like `Option`, `List` and other monads.

Comment: I found out eventually that probably the best way of dealing with this is to use scalaz **Validation** (with the very useful extension **ValidationNEL**) (see [link](http://blog.lunatech.com/2012/03/02/validation-scala)), which allows for a very expressive handling of the errors (and using match for advancing  processing).
Also an `Option[Try[T]]` or `Try[T]` monad might be very useful to have a **for** handling the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is pattern matching:

```
def fetchLastOrderFor(CustomerId:UUID)= {
customer = fetch Customer data from an Id
customer match{
  case Some(custData) => {
    info = fetch extra information for that customer (address?)
    lastOrder = fetch latest order of that customer
    lastOrder match{
      case Some(orderData) => ...
      case None => return invalid 
    }
  }
  case None => return invalid
}
```

Another is through a for-comprehension

```
def fetchLastOrderFor(CustomerId:UUID)= {
for{
  customer <- fetch Customer data from an Id
  info <- fetch extra information for that customer (address?)
  lastOrder <- fetch latest order of that customer
} yield { ...return some combination of the data above... }
```

Which really boils down to a bunch of `flatMap`s

So, it depends on your preference. I often feel that pattern matching or for comprehensions are more readable to a larger audience of developers, but it depends on the situation.

But, ultimately, most of this relies on using the right data structures. IE. the above example fits best with Option, Disjunction, or Validation.

Comment: can you elaborate a bit on  how it can be done with `Disjunction` or `Validation`? (`Option` is trivial of course)

Comment: I'll try to implement it with Validation or \/ . Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `Option`, you can put that all together as a for-comprehension.

```
def getCustomer(id: UUID): Option[Customer] = ???
def getCustomerInfo(customer: Customer): Option[CustomerInfo] = ???
def latestOrderForCustomer(customer: Customer): Option[Order]
def getOrderDetails(order: Order): Option[OrderDetails] = ???

def fetchLastOrderFor(customerId:UUID): Option[OrderDetails] = {
  for {
    customer     <- getCustomer(customerId)
    info         <- getCustomerInfo(customer)
    latestOrder  <- latestOrderForCustomer(customer)
    orderDetails <- getOrderDetails(order)
  } yield {
    orderDetails
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks you both for the suggestion on for comprehension, that sounds the most readable especially if longer sequences are involved... my only doubt would be in the fact that if I need to return not just the fact that orderdetails are there or not, but why they are not if the for comprehension works in the same way for `Either` or `Try` ... I will considered fully answered if I have clear in mind application with these latest types ...